# ¿Puedo simular una conexión HTTPS en un servidor local?

Tags: html, xampp, https, virtualhost

Tengo un virtual host hecho con xampp, Y estoy haciendo un formulario de login con HTML, Pero siempre me dice que la conexión no es segura cuando voy a poner la contraseña, ¿Se podria simular una conexión segura en el localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente:

Ve a:

> xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhost.conf

Y agrega: (modificando "DocumentRoot" con tu nombre de carpeta del proyecto.

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
 DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/CarpetaProyecto
 ServerName TuProyecto.com
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
 SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
 </VirtualHost>
```

Sino funciona puedes ir al archivo:

> xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf

Y modificar debajo de 
 **SSL Virtual Host Context**

Pero en este caso modificarias la ruta general.

Fuente: [Stackoverflow EN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801425/enabling-ssl-with-xampp)

Comment: Sino funciona es porque es para el puerto 443. Prueba con el puerto 80. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Hola, No me funciono, creo que el error es como quedo el archivo http-ssl, Mira como me quedó `<VirtualHost _default_:80>`

Comment: De no funcionar modificando el archivo SSL, prueba agregando en el archivo vhost.conf . De no funcionar con puerto 80, verifica con puerto 443. En el docs de stackoverflow en ingles, dice que hay que reiniciar el Apache con `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp disablessl` y  `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp enablessl` respectivamente.

Comment: @AlejandroValencia si te ha servido y solucionado el problema, recuerda [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)